# Unable to resolve inflate(int)

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater

So I am trying to inflate a layout in my activity but I keep getting this error "Cannot resolve method inflate(int)"

```
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View error = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.error_internet_connection);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there is no method `inflate(int)`. The methods available are `inflate(int, ViewGroup)` and `inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean)`.

Change

```
  View error = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.error_internet_connection);
```

to

```
 View error = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.error_internet_connection, null);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) you can find the documentation

Comment: LoL thank you so much ... man I forgot about this :D thanks again!